# Angular PUT request not reaching express code

Tags: angular

My app.js backend works perfectly in doing what I need. Postman updates correctly when testing, but the angular http PUT request isn't connecting for some reason. I'm really not sure why since the path is the same. Any help is appreciated.

Error:
`"Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/api/user/email/5dc1b5bccghdc22788b30922: 0 Unknown Error"`

Angular service

```
   const updateEmail: UserEmailChange = {
     id: id, oldEmail: oldEmail, newEmail: newEmail
   };

   return this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/api/user/email/' + updateEmail.id, updateEmail, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });

 }
```

app.js

```
app.put('/api/user/email/:id', (req, res) =>
User.update(
  {email: req.body.oldEmail},
  {email: req.body.newEmail}
  ).then( user => {
  console.log(user);
  res.json(user);
  // res.sendStatus(200);
  })


.then( user => {
console.log(user);
res.json(user);
// res.sendStatus(200);
}).catch(err => console.log(err)));
```

Comment: Well, you aren’t passing an actual id to the sever, you need to replace :id in the string with the actual id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should substitute the :id to a value in your service.

Comment: I updated the code above. I'm still getting an error after adding the value in place of :id

Comment: do you have trouble only with put requests? I mean your server set the CORS?

Comment: I can do POST and GET no problem in my app. Here's a screenshot of my console though for the PUT. It does mention CORS  https://postimg.cc/mz170zQX

Comment: it is a cors issue. for put request the cors is not set

Comment: I found the issue. Thanks for the help! My res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"); was missing PUT